# Let task explorer always run with realtime priority

Tags: process, priority

I have replaced task manager by process explorer from sysinternals. I would like this to always run at realtime, so that I can easily get it open when my system is *really* slow. I have noticed that it can take a while to start this program at those moments.

I have gone over the different options mentioned on SU. I can't change the shortcut, it immediately opens the .exe. I also can't use the task manager plugins/extensions, as I'm not using task manager.

Any idea what I could do? Preferably without installing any other software.

That is, if the priority would have any effect on starting the program.

Comment: Windows is designed specifically to NOT allow any executable to have higher priority than another when starting up, otherwise everyone would do it. You'll have to change it once it's started.

Comment: Can't edit the shortcut? Are you right-clicking and selecting Properties?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily.  create a batch file with the following and create a shortcut to it.

start /realtime \ps.exe

Comment: I have *replaced* task manager with process explorer. This means that whenever I click to open task manager, it open process explorer instead. It also means there is no shortcut involved anywhere in the process.

Comment: hm.  how did you do the replace?  you could possible rename taskmgr.exe and create an exe that calls the start ps.exe

Comment: It's an option in task explorer, so i have no idea what happens when replacing it.

Comment: it might be worth a shot.  worst case you just put it back.